# Matlab: convert NaNs from xlsread to blank

Tags: matlab, nan

The SOM 2.1 Toolbox is having issues with NaNs.
The code below only works for cell arrays and not double precision arrays of numbers.

```
[D, headers] = xlsread('Workbook2.xlsx', 'Sheet1', 'A2:BE101');
idx    = isnan(D);
D(idx) = {[]}

The following error occurred converting from cell to double:
Error using double
Conversion to double from cell is not possible.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you cannot do this : `D(idx) = {[]}` if you have a double array.

Then, `isnan` does not work with cell arrays. Consider the following cell:

```
a = cell(2,2);
a{1,1} = NaN;
a{1,2} = 2;
a{2,1} = NaN;
a{2,2} = 'hi';
```

you cab either use `isnan` element-wise (on each element of a cell), like:

```
isnan(a{1,1})
=
    1
```

or when all the elements of the cell are the same type, you can use `cell2mat` function first to convert it and then check all the elements with `isnan` at once, such as:

```
a = cell(2,2);
a{1,1} = NaN;
a{1,2} = 2;
a{2,1} = NaN;
a{2,2} = 3;

c=cell2mat(a)

c =

   NaN     2
   NaN     3

isnan(c)

ans =

     1     0
     1     0
```

So the answer depends on the `xls sheet` that you have, and the type of the data. You may use one of the mentioned options.

## Update

An example if you are using double array:

```
>> D = rand(2,3);
>> D(2,2) = NaN

D =

    0.8147    0.1270    0.6324
    0.9058       NaN    0.0975

>> idx = isnan(D)

idx =

     0     0     0
     0     1     0

>> D(idx) = []

D =

  Columns 1 through 3

    0.8147    0.9058    0.1270

  Columns 4 through 5

    0.6324    0.0975
```

Of course, it breaks the structure of the matrix into a vector.

Comment: xlsread is returning an array of doubles (not a cell array)                                              >> [D, headers] = xlsread('Workbook2.xlsx', 'Sheet1', 'A2:BE101');
>> class(D)

ans =

double

>> size(D)

ans =

   100    57

>>

Comment: so just do `D(idx) = []` and that should do it.

Comment: D(idx) = [] redimensioned the matrix.  >> [D, headers] = xlsread('Workbook2.xlsx', 'Sheet1', 'A2:BE101');
>> size(D)

ans =

   100    57

>> class(D)

ans =

double

>> idx    = isnan(D);
>> size(idx)

ans =

   100    57

>> D(idx) = [];
>> size(D)

ans =

           1        2557

>>

Comment: From Mathworks regarding SOM:  "One thing that was odd is that roughly 5% of the input data you trained the SOM with contains NaN values.  The algorithms that train the SOM are designed to operate on numerical data only.  As a result, NaN values can cause the training process to exhibit strange behavior.  In the case of your SOM, the output data contains nothing but NaN values.  I would look into removing the NaN values from your input data and retrain the SOM."

Comment: of  course it changes the structure of the matrix. Because it has no idea how to keep it without an empty value.

Comment: So then the way to solve this is to remove the input Excel data which is generating the NaNs?

Comment: You can either replace it with a number `1e-20`, Or you can rearrange the data using `reshape` function. So, firstly you change the matrix to a vector and then remove the NaNs and then reshape it back to a matrix with a different size.

Comment: Yet another option is to change the data while reading the excel file, To do so, you should use `processFcn, option from `xlsread` function. Check the help.